# Fetch Data from recordset and store it in list

Tags: java, list, recordset

I am trying to read and excel file and generate a pdf report

My problem faced is I am able to fetch records from excel file but unable to store it in ArrayList/List

When I print the list it shows only the last record of the excel file

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class testbean {

    private List<test> Testlist = new ArrayList<test>();

        String loc1 = UploadDownloadFileServlet.location;



    public List<test> getTestlist() throws FilloException {

        test t = new test();

            Fillo fillo = new Fillo();
        Connection connection = fillo.getConnection(loc1);
        String strQuery = "select * from Sheet1";
        Recordset recordset = connection.executeQuery(strQuery);
        System.out.println("path "+loc1);
        int k = recordset.getCount();
        System.out.println(k);
        while (recordset.next()) {
            t.setNAME(recordset.getField("NAME"));
            t.setSURNAME(recordset.getField("SURNAME"));
            t.setCITY(recordset.getField("CITY"));
            System.out.println(i);


                    }
                        Testlist.add(t);
            recordset.close();
        connection.close();


        return Testlist;
    }

    public void setLstPersonas(List<test> Testlist) {
        this.Testlist = Testlist;
    }

    public void exportarPDF(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws JRException, IOException, FilloException{
        File jasper = new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/newReport.jasper"));
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper.getPath(),null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(this.getTestlist()));



        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=jsfReporte.pdf");
        ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();           
    }
}
```

DATA in EXCEL

```
NAME    SURNAME CITY
JP      SHAH    MUM
RAHUL           BOM
ROHIT   RAUL    DEL
PARTH           BAN
JAY     PIKLE    BEN
```

OUTPUT in PDF

```
NAME SURNAME CITY
JAY PIKLE BEN
JAY PIKLE BEN
JAY PIKLE BEN
JAY PIKLE BEN
JAY PIKLE BEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoulud put Testlist.add(t); in your while loop

Comment: the last row is only fetched
So instead of 5 times only one is seen

Comment: put this test t = new test(); also in while loop

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
while (recordset.next()) {
                t.setNAME(recordset.getField("NAME"));
                t.setSURNAME(recordset.getField("SURNAME"));
                t.setCITY(recordset.getField("CITY"));
                System.out.println(i);


                        }
                            Testlist.add(t);
```

to this

```
while (recordset.next()) {
            t.setNAME(recordset.getField("NAME"));
            t.setSURNAME(recordset.getField("SURNAME"));
            t.setCITY(recordset.getField("CITY"));
            System.out.println(i);

            // this line should be inside the loop
            Testlist.add(t);

                    }
```

Comment: the last row is only fetched So instead of 5 times only one is seen

Comment: @DarshitSanghavi : did u keep the line inside the while loop ??

Comment: yes   it stopped the repeated rows or duplicate data but only last row is fetched

Comment: update your code where you are accessing the list and priting values , separately

Answer (score 0):

It is a List of list. TestList  is having multiple test.
instead of initializing test in public,initialize within Whileloop before adding values to test. and Add Test  to testlist within whileloop.

I was having similar issue.Mine was List of Maps.Like you mine last record was overriding the previous records and adding a new record. it got resolved when I initialized the map within while loop.